# Wordpress write into database with primary key autoincrement not working

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to write into a database table in a PHP script. This is my code:

```
$tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'test';

    $wpdb->insert( $tablename, array(
        'id' => DEFAULT,
        'post_id' => $post_id, 
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        array( '%s', '%s', '%s' ) 
    ));
```

After trying out my code I've got following error:

```
[29-Sep-2018 17:34:29 UTC] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected 'DEFAULT' (T_DEFAULT) in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-content\themes\DiviChild\test.php on line 32
```

My table has a primary key "id" which should be autoincrement. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if "id" is set to be autoincrement then there is no need to include `'id'=>DEFAULT,` while inserting record. It will be set automatically in your table when new record is inserted.

It seems there is mistake in argument.
`$wpdb->insert` takes 3 arguments and it seems you've included 3rd argument into 2nd argument.

```
 $wpdb->insert( $tablename, 
   array(
    'post_id' => $post_id, 
    'user_id' => $user_id
   ),
   array( '%d', '%s' ) 
);
```

Removed `id` as it's autoincrement and modified formatting array assuming `post_id` to be numeric based on your comment.

Comment: But without it I get an other error: [29-Sep-2018 18:17:36 UTC] WordPress-Datenbank-Fehler Unknown column '0' in 'field list' für Abfrage INSERT INTO `test` (`post_id`, `user_id`, `0`) VALUES ('389', NULL, '')

Comment: If you are removing `'id'=>DEFAULT,` then you would also have to edit values array from `array( '%s', '%s', '%s' ) ` to  `array( '%s', '%s' ) `

On a side note, for autoincrement, it should have been %d instead of %s.

Comment: also, if post_id is a numeric value then format array should be `array( '%d', '%s' )`